# Pie charts and geopandas map

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to represent the ethnic distribution within each region of my map.

I'm a newbie in geopandas and until now I can just make a map that shows the share of one single ethnic group by region.

My code is the following:

```
geodf.plot(column="resid_preto", cmap="Blues", figsize=(20,12), 
edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.9, legend=False)

plt.axis('off')
```

Where 'resid_preto' is a column that contains the share of the black population within the region

I want to make a map like this one. So, I could have the representation of all ethnic groups in one single map instead of creating one map per group
[image]

Comment: I'm also trying to accomplish that. So far I've found that geopands has the `kind` parameter (https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html?highlight=pie)  but it is not working for me. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no straight forward way to do this with `geopandas`. But combining it with scatter from `pyplot` the desired result can be obtained.

The first trick is to obtain the `x,y` coordinates where the pie chart is going to be plotted. In my case I used the [`centroid`](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.centroid.html?highlight=centroids) tool of `geopandas` with the x and y methods, e.g., the x and y coordinates are given by (`i` is the row index in the geopandas DataFrame):

```
centroids = geo_df.centroid
x_coord = centroids.x[i]
y_coord = centroids.y[i]
```

The next step is to use pyplot to create a [pie chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) and store the returned structure, which comprises, among other things, a list of patches with the wedges of the pie:

```
wedges=plt.pie([1,1,1])
```

The 3rd step is to create a plot object and then plot the geopandas DataFrame with the [plot API](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot), e.g.,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
geo_df.boundary.plot(ax=ax,zorder=1,edgecolor='black')
```

Finally, use scatter to add the pie charts on top of the geopandas plot. The `for` loop is to add each of the 3 wedges obtained from `plot.pie([1,1,1])` (in case of more wedges just change this. There must be a more efficient/elegant way of doing this):

```
piecolor=['b','g','y']
for j in range(3):
 ax.scatter([x_coord],[y_coord],marker=(wedges[0][j].get_path().vertices.tolist()),facecolor=piecolors[j], s=800)
plt.show()
```

The trick is to pass a non-default marker to `scatter`, in this case the wedges. For each element in `wedges` first get the path, then the vertices and finally convert it to a list and that's the marker.

Comment: Genial solution! I had to do this for a whole dataframe, so in the last step i embedded the "for j in range" loop inside a "df.itertuples()", so that I cold pass the xcoord, ycoord, and pie wedges directly for each dataframe row.