# How can I fix the deformed piecharts on a map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

I am plotting a pie chart per country with some statistics. A sample of my data (where all the columns except for geometry and size are categories to be shown by the pie charts) looks like this:

[image: sample data]

Using the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71900664/7838925), I am able to produce a scatter plot with pie charts from the 'sample' data that looks reasonable:

[image: plot]

This is the code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# utility function inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib
def draw_pie(dist, xpos, ypos, size, ax):
    # for incremental pie slices
    cumsum = np.cumsum(dist)
    cumsum = cumsum / cumsum[-1]
    pie = [0] + cumsum.tolist()

    size = math.sqrt(size)
    
    colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "black", "red", "yellow", "pink"]
    for i, (r1, r2) in enumerate(zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:])):
        angles = np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2)
        x = [0] + np.cos(angles).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(angles).tolist()

        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])
        ax.scatter([xpos], [ypos], marker=xy, s=size, color=colors[i], alpha=1)

    return ax



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,40))

for idx, row in sample.iterrows():

    ax = draw_pie([row[cols].tolist()], row.geometry.x, row.geometry.y, row["size"], ax)

cx.add_basemap(ax, crs=countries_centers.crs, source=cx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
```

However, upon zooming in, I see that the pie charts are broken:

[image: zoomedin]

This is for a publication so the quality needs to be perfect. I have no idea what's causing this and how to fix it even after going through the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Please review #3 of [Creating Effective Stack Overflow Questions](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/Creating_Effective_StackOverflow_Questions.html) for posting your dataframe. Do not post data as a screenshot.

Comment: It's not a pie plot unless you're using `ax.pie`. This is a scatter plot with a custom marker.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks and do you happen to know any way to put pie charts on a map like i tried and have them display correctly?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/56277645/7758804, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45266955/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68915932/7758804. I think the last two use cartopy though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73534138/7758804 with plotly instead of matplotlib